# Orderby the sum of several numeric custom meta fields

Tags: wp-query

I would like to know how I can do the following in the simplest way.

Say I have several numerical meta fields (more than two).

I want to be able to orderby the sum of those meta fields. But it is not all of them. This depends on user input.

It could be meta field 1+ meta field 2, or meta field 2 + meta field 3 etc.

My first thought was to create new meta fields where the calculation was already done. But it will be a lot of meta fields to cover for each possible variation.

So I was wondering if it is possible to do the calculation in orderby somehow.

Comment: Hi Tobias, welcome to WPSE. Please feel free to [take the tour](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour). My guess is that you'd need to use a custom SQL query for this, and it would depend on whether this is possible in straight SQL (I'd be surprised if it wasn't). What have you tried searching for so far?

Comment: I have tried the hard way of adding a field for every possible combination (not recommended). I also think that straight SQL will be the best way to do it. Although the easiest way would be if this would be possible with wp_query and orderby. But I have tried to find a solution with wp_query on the Internet but came up with nothing. It is possible to do several orderby's but it doesn't give me the exact solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not within realm of native [orderby parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) in query. They are limited to an order by individual meta fields and have no ways to implement aggregate of them.

You would have to either write custom SQL for it or query a broader set and finalize calculations on PHP side. It is hard to guess which would be more fitting, since you don't cover your use case in detail.

Comment: Although I agree with your recommendation, it is possible to order by multiple meta fields since WP4.2 (see https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query). However, there's no way to order on an aggregate, as far as I know.

Comment: Good call, I forgot and it's not well documented in Codex. :)